# Unable to find one-to-many relationship, entity: moj_lawsystem, referencing entity: activityparty

Tags: dynamics-crm, uci

In -UCI- unified interface: We have - an inconsistent fault.
it comes back from time to time. When editing a field code of type ACTIVITYPARTY. and plant him with values from certain entities. When saving: The error pops up: "**Unable to find one-to-many relationship, entity: moj_lawsystem, referencing entity: activityparty"** or :"**Unable to find one-to-many relationship, entity: moj_profesional, referencing entity: activityparty**"
Another thing - the fault is restored only when the field is edited by code and not manually. Manual works fine. In the CLASSIC version the code works properly.
Does anyone have a solution?

I tried clearing cache,iisreset, and that didn't seem to help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please visit the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research or search for related topics on SO. If you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.